# Error message "The Id has an invalid format" when setting Start datetime object

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I could use your help to understand what the error message in the last line tries to tell me.

The second line is ok, completely possible that the Id is not yet set before I save the Appointment.
But why can I change Subject and Location, but not Start?

```
app = new Appointment(ews);
// unid = app.Id.UniqueId; <- throws error "The Id has an invalid format"
app.Subject = ce.subject;
app.Location = ce.location;
app.Start = DateTime.ParseExact(ce.startDate + " " + ce.startTime, datestring + 
            " " + timestring, null); // <- throws "The Id has an invalid format"
```

Comment: so basically if you comment app.Start = ... it is working?

Comment: I didn't try to comment it, because Start and End are required to successfully save an entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the signature of the method you are using to extract the date

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

It could throw a FormatException if

1. s or format is an empty string
2. s does not contain a date and time that corresponds to the pattern specified in format.
3. The hour component and the AM/PM designator in s do not agree.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: It's not that line of code that is throwing an exception? I guessed that "The Id has an invalid format" is a FormatException...

Comment: 2) was it. I checked and the JSON returned from the client differs from the JSON I sent there. It was even easier than what I did. Now I changed string to DateTime, and then I used `app.Start = ce.startDate.Date + ce.startTime.TimeOfDay;`, same for End, and leapt forward to the next obstacle... the only question remaining is "Why is the error message telling me sth about an Id?"

Comment: I think "The Id has an invalid format" is the default message of a FormatException (not sure, just going by memory here)